# why my Python code is running?

Tags: catkin, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I playing alot with :::ROS and I realize this:

I can modify my Python app and start it again by doing:

> $rosrun mypkg mypython.py

no need to go back to catkin workspace and do catkin_make

but if I do that (catkin_make) everything works too...

then what is the sense behind the **catkin_make** command

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257814/why-my-python-code-is-running?/) by [LbrRobix](https://answers.ros.org/users/29792/lbrrobix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can for sure run the code iwthout *making* it  since that is python (a script language) BUT:

if you are using messages and services you will need a new autogenerated python code...

look the doc in the [ros page](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber)

3rd parragraph

> We use CMake as our build system and,
> yes, you have to use it even for
> Python nodes. This is to make sure
> that the autogenerated Python code for
> messages and services is created.

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0